# neural network predicts the same number for every handwritten digit or false number

Tags: tensorflow

I've tried to built a handwritten digit recognition neural network based on the mnist dataset and when I test it with the test images provided by the data set itself it seems to work pretty well (that's what the function test_predict is for). Now I would like to step it up and have the network recognise some actual handwritten digits that I've taken photos of. I provide some photos of individual digits and they all look something like this:
[view image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HbXOl.png)
***The problem is: My neural network's prediction for this one of my test image is "1".***
Do you have any idea why this is happening? Any advise is welcome. Thank you in advance.
Here's my code :

```
     from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function

# Import TensorFlow v2.
     import tensorflow as tf
     from tensorflow.keras import Model, layers
     import numpy as np

# MNIST dataset parameters.
     num_classes = 10 # total classes (0-9 digits).
     num_features = 784 # data features (img shape: 28*28).

# Training Parameters
     learning_rate = 0.001
     training_steps = 1000
     batch_size = 32
     display_step = 100

# Network Parameters
# MNIST image shape is 28*28px, we will then handle 28 sequences of 28 timesteps for every sample.
     num_input = 28 # number of sequences.
     timesteps = 28 # timesteps.
     num_units = 32 # number of neurons for the LSTM layer.

# Prepare MNIST data.
     from tensorflow.keras.datasets import mnist
     (x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
# Convert to float32.
     x_train, x_test = np.array(x_train, np.float32), np.array(x_test, np.float32)
# Flatten images to 1-D vector of 784 features (28*28).
     x_train, x_test = x_train.reshape([-1, 28, 28]), x_test.reshape([-1, num_features])
# Normalize images value from [0, 255] to [0, 1].
     x_train, x_test = x_train / 255., x_test / 255.

# Use tf.data API to shuffle and batch data.
    train_data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_train, y_train))
    train_data = train_data.repeat().shuffle(5000).batch(batch_size).prefetch(1)

# Create LSTM Model.
     class LSTM(Model):
         # Set layers.
         def __init__(self):
             super(LSTM, self).__init__()
             # RNN (LSTM) hidden layer.
             self.lstm_layer = layers.LSTM(units=num_units)
             self.out = layers.Dense(num_classes)

         # Set forward pass.
         def call(self, x, is_training=False):
             # LSTM layer.
             x = self.lstm_layer(x)
             # Output layer (num_classes).
             x = self.out(x)
             if not is_training:
                # tf cross entropy expect logits without softmax, so only
                # apply softmax when not training.
                x = tf.nn.softmax(x)
             return x

# Build LSTM model.
     lstm_net = LSTM()

# Cross-Entropy Loss.
# Note that this will apply 'softmax' to the logits.
     def cross_entropy_loss(x, y):
         # Convert labels to int 64 for tf cross-entropy function.
         y = tf.cast(y, tf.int64)
         # Apply softmax to logits and compute cross-entropy.
         loss = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y, logits=x)
         # Average loss across the batch.
         return tf.reduce_mean(loss)

# Accuracy metric.
     def accuracy(y_pred, y_true):
         # Predicted class is the index of highest score in prediction vector (i.e. argmax).
         correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y_pred, 1), tf.cast(y_true, tf.int64))
         return tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32), axis=-1)

# Adam optimizer.
     optimizer = tf.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate)

# Optimization process. 
def run_optimization(x, y):
    # Wrap computation inside a GradientTape for automatic differentiation.
    with tf.GradientTape() as g:
        # Forward pass.
        pred = lstm_net(x, is_training=True)
        # Compute loss.
        loss = cross_entropy_loss(pred, y)
        
    # Variables to update, i.e. trainable variables.
    trainable_variables = lstm_net.trainable_variables

    # Compute gradients.
    gradients = g.gradient(loss, trainable_variables)
    
    # Update weights following gradients.
    optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, trainable_variables))

# Run training for the given number of steps.
for step, (batch_x, batch_y) in enumerate(train_data.take(training_steps), 1):
    # Run the optimization to update W and b values.
    run_optimization(batch_x, batch_y)
    
    if step % display_step == 0:
        pred = lstm_net(batch_x, is_training=True)
        loss = cross_entropy_loss(pred, batch_y)
        acc = accuracy(pred, batch_y)
        print("step: %i, loss: %f, accuracy: %f" % (step, loss, acc))

# select an image from the list Ensemble_Chiffre_extf.
     taszwira = Ensemble_Chiffre_extf[0]
     cv2_imshow(taszwira)

# Convert to float32.
     taszwira = np.array(taszwira, np.float32)
# Flatten images to 1-D vector of 784 features (28*28).
     resized = cv2.resize(taszwira,(28,28),interpolation = cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
     newing = tf.keras.utils.normalize(resized,axis=1)
     newing = np.array(newing).reshape(-1,28,28)

# Normalize images value from [0, 255] to [0, 1].
     newing = newing / 255.
# predection
     pred = lstm_net(newing, is_training=False)
     print(np.argmax(pred))
```

the result of 'print(np.argmax(pred))' = 1 but the image have such number 3 . i test other image that is 5 but the prediction is 7 : [View image 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dAuvr.png)

Comment: Welcome to the Stack.  Do the bars at the top and bottom appear in all the images?  Since it is regular (simple straight line) it might be possible to clean the image up first.

Comment: thank you .. no the bars do not appear it's just the traces of the screen captrue that I made. the image is well cleaned. I used the vertical and horizontal projections to frame the image well.  i have updated the photo above if you want to see.

Comment: Your images are just too different from the MNIST dataset, this dataset is not meant to create a general digit recognition system.

Comment: several general projects like that work with mnist that's why I work with this database. Do you have any idea or proposal?